# APPCrash Kernelbase.dll

Tags: .net, windows, crash

I'm getting the below error on a particular application. this error presents for any user who tries to run the application directly on the workstation. However, when the same user remotes in with RDP or dameware the error is no longer present.

This made me think it may be an issue with the graphics driver with I uninstalled and reinstalled with the latest version.

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the application, and even though it doesn't have anything to do with this error, as it regularly presents with a `.netframwork` error requiring that `.net` be uninstalled and reinstalled I did this as well.

This is the only one of many Workstations with the exact same configuration and environment presenting with this issue.

If at all possible I need a fix that won't involve rebuilding the machine

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: ENPSClient.exe
  Application Version:  8.2.0.236
  Application Timestamp:    58a4cdac
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18409
  Fault Module Timestamp:   53159a86
  Exception Code:   c06d007e
  Exception Offset: 0000c42d
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    3081
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Temporarily fixed the problem the other day by removing the application and .net  and searching for and deleting any leftover regkeys then reinstalling however the problem came back with a new error preceding the original.                           "D3DCompiler_47.dll is missing".                                                Tried copying it from my laptop to the workstation with the problem, but still get the same error.

Comment: Does downgrading to .NET Framework 4.5.2 help? Might be the same issue as https://github.com/HearthSim/Hearthstone-Deck-Tracker/issues/3662.